# How to capitalise last letter of string in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried this:

```
def capitalize_first_last_letters(str1):
 str1 = result = str1.title()
 result =  ""
 for word in str1.split():
    result += word[:-1] + word[-1].upper() + " "
 return result[:-1]
print(capitalize_first_last_letters("resource"))
```

Output:

```
ResourcE
```

I just want to capitalize the last letter.

Comment: Oops, my bad. I need to remove the str1 = result = str1.title(). Now it's working as expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply slice, turn to `str.upper()` the last letter and add together:

```
s = 'Resource'

s[:-1] + s[-1].upper()
# 'ResourcE'
```

Answer (score 2):

To capitalise just the last character of a string:

```
 string = "resource"
 result = string[:-1] + string[-1].upper()
```

Result:

```
'resourcE'
```

`string[:-1]` is the substring from the start of the string, stopping 1 position before the end.

Answer (score 2):

Use title after reversing the string and reverse it back

`s[::-1].title()[::-1]`

Comment: If `s` has multiple words in it, and you want every words last letter `capitalized`, this is the way. If you just want the last letter of the last word, `str.capitalize()` is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you come here looking for a solution that will work with Pandas try this one. This solution will work even if you have NULLs.

```
def uppercase_last_letter(series):
    """Func to uppercase the last letter in a string"""
    return series.map(lambda x: (x[:-1] + x[-1].upper()) if type(x) == str else x)


df[col1] = uppercase_last_letter(df[col1])
```